# calculation of two numbers based on a percentage of original number?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a known final number. Lets say that is 100. Also I have a percentage difference between original two number. That is number 1 was 10% more than number 2. How do I find the two numbers. I want to do this for a lot of numbers. So any general formula for this would be helpful. Basically I need to find the two numbers that are 1 number is 10% higher than other number but there sum has to equal to 100.

Comment: Is this really a stats question? It seems like a plain mathematics question. As the tag says, it's arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
y=100

x1=1.1*x2 #110% of x2
x2=?

y=x1+x2
100=1.1*x2+x2
100=2.1*x2
100/2.1=x2
47.61905=x2 #circa

x1=1.1*x2
x1=47.61905*1.1
x1=52.38096 #circa
```

Check:

```
x1+x2=y
52.38096+47.61905=100
```

?

seems maybe correct ^^

**numbers are circa, but equations should be good**

Comment: This seems absolutely fine. Let me just confirm and thank you once again later on. You are a life saver.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Thank you for the quick reply. This helps a lot.

Comment: @AhsanTech nice, im happy it helped you :-)